# Ng-show based on timestamp

Tags: angularjs

I have a

As a scope I have: `$scope.getDatetime = new Date();`
And I wanna make the following work:

```
<span ng-show="getDatetime > foobar.datetime">Foobar</span>
```

The `foobar.datetime` is from ng-repeat with the format of: `2014-08-20 01:45:15`

So I only wanna show that element, when current time is bigger then the datetime given.

Thought it was a easy as my example above, but it isn't - and I can't figure out if it's even possible without using plugins.

Comment: So is foobar.datetime a string then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly, then your issue is that your comparing a string and a date object.  Try:

```
<span ng-show="getDatetime > getDate(foobar.datetime)">Foobar</span>
```

And in your javascript:

```
$scope.getDate = function(date) {
    return new Date(date);
}
```

Comment: Not working: ``` Syntax Error: Token 'Date' is an unexpected token at column 19 of the expression [getDatetime > new Date(foobar.datetime)] starting at [Date(foobar.datetime)].```

Comment: Forgot you can't create dates in an angular expression.  I've edited my answer with a solution that should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your date to a timestamp, then you can compare the 2 dates, perhaps try using a filter to convert to a time stamp.